# Does the "birth date" attribute in Schema.org/Person need to be in a specific format?

Tags: schema.org, date-format

When creating structured data using Schema.org/Person, does the birth date need to be in a specific format?

Currently on the website I am working on the birth dates are written as: "15 Jan 1980"

Should it be written as "15.01.1980" or perhaps using hyphens instead of the period sign?

Is it a specific format that should be followed?

This question applies for any Schema.org type that has a "date" field, not just for `Person`.

Comment: I just tested and used **Apr 8 1981** as the date format. When validating the page with the Google structured data testing tool, it shows **1981-04-08** under the results snippet. So, Google is smart enough to make the connection himself.

However, Bing markup validator shows "Apr 8 1981".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Schema.org's getting started guide](https://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_dates) specifies the expected format for dates.

`YYYY-MM-DD` format should be used when it is just a date without a time:

```
<time datetime="2011-04-01">04/01/11</time>
```

It also says how to add the time of day and deal with durations.